# Optimizar codigo python

Tags: python

Tengo este código para eliminar mensajes, pero lo veo bastante redundante, he probado a intentar optimizarlo con algun bucle y siguiendo las directrices de algun que otro post que leí googleando, pero no logro que funcione correctamente, a veces no me detecta el comando, otras me salta los bucles.

```
    if texto.startswith('/delete'):
        if texto == '/delete all':
            async for messages in client.iter_messages(from_channel_id):
                await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, messages)

        # borra los mensajes del dia indicado
        elif texto.startswith('/delete day'):
            date = datetime.strptime(texto[12:22], '%d/%m/%Y')
            await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, event.message)

            async for messages in client.iter_messages(from_channel_id):
                if messages.date.__str__()[0:10] == date.__str__()[0:10]:
                    await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, messages)

        # borra los mensajes antiguos hasta el dia indicado
        elif texto.startswith('/delete until'):
            date = datetime.strptime(texto[14:24], '%d/%m/%Y')
            await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, event.message)

            async for messages in client.iter_messages(from_channel_id):
                if messages.date.__str__()[0:10] < date.__str__()[0:10]:
                    await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, messages)

        # borra los mensajes antiguos hasta el dia indicado
        elif texto.startswith('/delete from'):
            date = datetime.strptime(texto[13:23], '%d/%m/%Y')
            await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, event.message)

            async for messages in client.iter_messages(from_channel_id):
                if messages.date.__str__()[0:10] <= date.__str__()[0:10]:
                    await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, messages)

        elif texto == '/delete':
            await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, event.message)
```

Si me pudieran dar alguna directiva que me ayude a aprender por mi mismo se lo agradecería mucho.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si no entiendo mal el código, debe hacer lo siguiente:

- Siempre que `texto` comience por `"/delete"` debe borrar al menos `event.message`
- Si sigue por `"all"` debe borrar además el resto de mensajes.
- Si sigue en cambio por `"day"`, `"until"`, o `"from"`, llevará a continuación una fecha y deberá borrar respectivamente los mensajes con esa fecha (day), todos los anteriores a esa fecha sin incluirla (until), o todos los posteriores a la fecha dada, inclusive (from). Este último caso lo tendrías mal implementado pues el comparador debería ser `>=` y no `<=` como tú tienes.

En tu implemetnación hay mucho código repetitivo, lo que es un *bad smell*, y entiendo que quieras buscar una forma más eficiente, entendiendo aquí por eficiencia el disminuir esas repeticiones para que el código sea más mantenible (y no eficiencia en tiempo de ejecución, que esa no mejoraría).

Aquí van algunas ideas:

- Todos esos bucles `async for` que tienes son idénticos, salvo por la condición de comparación de fechas, por lo que podríamos pensar en extraerlos a una función que recibiría como parámetros la fecha y el comparador a usar.
- Para poder transmitir un comparador como parámetro podemos usar el módulo `operator`, que define funciones como `operator.eq()`, `operator.lt()`, `operator.ge()`, etc para representar a las operaciones `==`, `<`, `>=`, etc. respectivamente.
- Para unificar el tratamiento de las fechas y no depender de en qué posición comiecen dentro de la cadena `texto` podemos usar `texto.split(" ")` para dividirlo por los espacios y así obtener en el elemento `[0]` el texto `"/delete"`, en el elemento `[1]` la cadena `"all"`, `"day"`, `"until"` o `"from"` y en el elemento `[2]` la fecha.
- De esto no estoy muy seguro, pero creo que podrías comparar las fechas directamente, sin pasarlas a string. Es decir, en lugar de comparar `message.date.__str__()[0:10]` con `date.__str__()[0:10]`, directamente puedes comparar `message.date` con `date`. Digo que no estoy muy seguro porque depende de que ambos objetos sean de tipo `datetime`. Si lo son, no hay problema. Si no, quizás sea necesario esa conversión a cadena que tú haces. En todo caso en vez de `cosa.__str__()`, puedes hacer `str(cosa)`, que queda mucho más limpio.
- Para decidir qué operador (`eq()`, `lt()` o `ge()`) debes usar según el valor del texto, sin tener que poner condicionales, puedes tener un diccionario con posibles valores del texto y qué operador corresponde a cada caso.
- Para cubrir también el caso `"all"` como uno más, en lugar de tener que tratarlo de forma especial, podemos pasarlo como comparador a la función que hace el borrado, y que esta haga que si el comparador es "all" borre el mensaje sin comprobar su fecha.

Usando estas ideas, el código no es necesariamente más corto. También tengo mis dudas de que sea más legible (posiblemente no). La principal ventaja es que se elimina repetición de código, y que el bucle de borrado, la extracción de la fecha, la comparación con otra fecha, etc. son operaciones que aparecen ahora una sola vez. Esto ayuda a la mantenibilidad por si tienes que cambiar una de esas operaciones poder hacerlo en un solo lugar en vez de tener que hacer múltiples buscar y reemplazar, proclives a errores.

Queda así (obviamente no puedo testearlo, no garantizo que funcione a la primera):

```
async def borra_mensajes(condicion, date):
    """Esta función borra todos los mensajes que cumplan cierta
    condición con respecto a la fecha dada.

    Si la condición es "all", los borra todos sin mirar la fecha.

    Si la condición es None retorna sin borrar nada

    En otro caso ejecuta condicion() sobre la fecha del mensaje y la
    fecha dada y elimina los que retorne True"""

    if condicion is None:
        return
    async for msg in client.iter_messages(from_channel_id):
        if condicion == "all" or condicion(message.date, date):
            await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, msg)

# Diccionario que asocia casos en el comando con operadores de comparación
casos = {
    "day": operator.eq,   # ==
    "until": operator.lt, # <
    "from": operator.ge   # >=
}

if texto.startswith("/delete"):
    # El mensaje del evento hay que borrarlo de todas formas
    await client.delete_messages(from_channel_id, event.message)
    partes = texto.split(" ")
    if partes[1:]:           # Si hay sub-comando extra
        caso = partes[1]
        if caso == "all":
            condicion = "all"
            date = "No importa"
        elif caso in casos:
            condicion = casos[caso]
            date = datetime.strptime(partes[2], "%d/%m/%Y")
        else:
            # Por si acaso vienen cosas raras como /delete foobar
            # no borraríamos nada más
            condicion = None
            date = "No importa"
        borra_mensajes(condicion, date)
```